# React Material-UI on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, webpack

does anyone know that React+Material-UI can use on ASP.NET .

I'm try use React.NET , but it's cannot use Material-UI conponent .

even use webpack to compiler it or Material-UI just only for NodeJS ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the error?
Material-UI and any other javascript library is totally not (ASP.NET/Django/Spring/Node.js) related, these are just a bunch of assets files.

Comment: oh i solve this issue  , it's  need add extra webpack.config parameter
resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {},
        extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js']
    }
reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042157/correct-way-to-require-material-ui-by-webpack 
Thank you reply :D